# sql server , case statement issues 2014

Tags: sql-server, case

How can I fix the syntax errors I'm getting with the below query?

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING (A. columnname 2,3) Alias
     ,SUBSTRING(A.columnname, 7,10) Alias2 
FROM Tablename A
left join Tablename B on B.YR = 2017
AND A.columnname = SUBSTRING(b.Columnname 2,3) 
CASE 
WHEN B.columnname = 5 THEN  5
WHEN A.columnname <>'NA' THEN SUBSTRING(B. Columnname 2,3)
END AS First_Quater
INTO ##Results2017
GROUP BY SUBSTRING (A. columnname 2,3) Alias,
SUBSTRING(A.columnname, 7,10) Alias2,First Quater
```

Comment: Can you post the syntax error?

Comment: I see some missing commas inside the SUBSTRING calls

Comment: Try to run the query, look at the error message you get and then check the syntax you should be using? Your syntax is totally wrong, so you might want to start with something simpler first, and then add new parts when the first thing works